# BackgroundJS for Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-service

I saw plugin [BackgroundJS](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-background) yesterday and searching for one working on android, but didn't find anything

Is there any for android ?

If answer is yes, then please give me a link.

Or if it isn't :

How can I call my android service with Javascript (in phonegap)

com.abc.def -> BackgroundService.java